# Are dynamic Make Dependencies possible?

Tags: bash, makefile, gnu-make

Consider the following example `Makefile`:

```
.PHONY: all

all: Coffee_With_Milk Coffee_With_noMilk

%_With_%: Kitchen
    # Parse the parts from $@ and do stuff
```

As you can see, I produce `Coffee_With_Milk` and `Coffee_With_noMilk` with it.

When I not only have the choice `[Coffee]` and `[Milk, noMilk]` but `[Coffee, Tea, Juice, Vodka, Coke]` and `[Milk, Sugar, Lemon, Marshmallow, nothing]`, I would have to write all 5x5=25 combinations into the `all: <combination1> <combination2> <...>` line.

Is there any way to create it dynamically?

Comment: First, this target pattern `%_With_%` is not legal.  You can only have one `%` in a pattern.  The second (and subsequent) `%` are not pattern matchers, they are just literal `%` characters.

Comment: Thank you, I did not know this yet. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `foreach` function:

```
BEVERAGE := Coffee Tea Juice Vodka Coke
ADDIN := Milk Sugar Lemon Marshmallow nothing

COMBOS := $(foreach B,$(BEVERAGE),$(foreach A,$(ADDIN),$(B)_With_$(A)))
```

As I mentioned in my comment, though, you won't be able to use a pattern rule like the one you've mentioned.